# DELETE FROM with LIMIT not working - Error 1064

Tags: mysql, limit

Basically i have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   `transactions` a
WHERE  Round(( tender1 - `change` ), 2) != (SELECT Round(Sum(total), 2)
                                            FROM   `transactions` b
                                            WHERE  b.trans_no = a.trans_no)
       AND tender1 != 0
LIMIT  1
```

which is fine and returns a single line but if i change the statement to delete

```
DELETE FROM `transactions` a
WHERE  Round(( tender1 - `change` ), 2) != (SELECT Round(Sum(total), 2)
                                            FROM   `transactions` b
                                            WHERE  b.trans_no = a.trans_no)
       AND tender1 != 0
LIMIT 1
```

this returns an error 1064 invalid syntax

any ideas???

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. How can you know which is the first row, and that you won't delete any arbitrary row matching your conditions ?

Comment: basically this query flags up any duplicate records for me (removing the limit 1 from the select statement), i dont specifically care which one i delete, as long as i delete one of them :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have the `LIMIT` there but I think this would work if you want to delete an arbitrary row:

```
DELETE FROM `transactions` WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM `transactions` a 
    WHERE ROUND((TENDER1 - `CHANGE`),2) != (SELECT ROUND(SUM(TOTAL),2) 
                                            FROM  `transactions` b 
                                            WHERE b.trans_no = a.TRANS_NO) 
    AND TENDER1 != 0 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: problem is this table has no unique id for each line (not my design!!) so it is a bit awkward :(